# php torrent tacker (based on Torrent RW php file) with external files inside .torrent

Tags: php, utorrent, torrent

Please help me as my php is not too good.

I'm trying to make a Torrent tracker.
The main idea is to give user .torrent file (always different, depending on the content) with different external file.

For example:
user wants to download

```
http://my-domain.com/Cooking-Book.torrent
```

the original file Cooking-Book.zip is on another server, and downloading starts at URL

```
http://other-domain.com/Cooking-Book
```

At this moment I have each part working separately, but I can't combine them, please help.

For downloading external file I have load.php (and it starts downloading file when I request it) They are all small files less than 3 MB

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
   echo file_get_contents('http://other-domain.com/'.$filename);
?>
```

For creating .torrent file I use Torrent WR php file (https://github.com/adriengibrat/torrent-rw/blob/master/Torrent.php) I require "Torrent.php" in my custom getTorent.php

```
<?php
   require_once 'Torrent.php';
   $torrent = new Torrent( array( 'test.mp3', 'test.jpg' ), 'http://torrent.tracker/annonce' );
   $torrent->send();
?>
```

When I request getTorent.php it starts downloading "my-domain.com.torrent".
Then I open it with uTorrent client (there 2 files: "test.mp3" and "test.jpg"), but they aren't downloading. (Example files on my server)

Please help me change these php files, that give getTorent.php the .torrent file, so it will start downloading the external file.

Thank you very much! And hope it will help somebody else too.

Comment: P2P Downloading works when they're people which are *seeding* the file. http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/peersharing/a/torrenthandbook.htm

Comment: OK, my server always can share and provide the downloading process, how to realize it?

Comment: Using your web server to seed a torrent would require said server to have downloaded the files onto the hard drive. This proves expensive in terms of space. If you're creating the torrent on the fly. I'd imagine that it's just a created magnet file with no one seeding the torrent its self, not using P2P downloading as much in web development. I have no idea how to approach this method past this point

Comment: As far as I understand, my server is sufficient to support the process of data transfer. (maybe some php files) Now "test.mp3" and "test.jpg" have already on my server, but they aren't downloading. After solving it, think It's posible to transfer data from anoter server trought my.

Comment: Your script currently offers the file as a download instead of using the torrent. It seems to me your web server should have a torrent client to seed the file.

Comment: Found clear php torrent server https://github.com/christeredvartsen/php-bittorrent-tracker but it's impossible for me even to install it, not to combine with creating .torrent